# BGAppRefreshTask in the BackgroundTasks

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have this code that show a message "Msg Background" when the application is in Background. What I need is that as long as the application continues in the background show that message every 2 minutes (just an example of time). So far the code I have shows the message only once, apparently this sentence is not working properly.

```
UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval (UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
```

I also have this warning: 'setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use a BGAppRefreshTask in the BackgroundTasks framework instead

I am using swift 5 and Xcode 11

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBSpAt5zqvbh73FmG_Kb6xpiFMkWRmHppg")
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.backgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Msg Background")
}

}
```

Comment: The minimum background fetch interval is nothing like 2 minutes. It would be more like 30-60 minutes. You need to call the completion handler that was passed to `performFetch` to indicate whether your app fetched new data or not. Failure to call the completion handler will result in your app not receiving any further background fetch opportunities. iOS also monitors whether you actually perform network operations as well as the times of day that your app says that it fetched new data to determine how often and when your background fetch is scheduled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Paulw11 said, it's not called in fixed interval. The OS controls when it is going to be executed. We cannot expect the specific time because of it.

You probably know this, but I'm going to add this bit just in case, [setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623100-setminimumbackgroundfetchinterva) has deprecated on iOS 13 and later. You might want to consider to use [BackgroundTasks Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/) instead.

but if you want to test performFetchWithCompletionHandler, you can use XCode Navigation Bar > Debug > perform Background Fetch.

[screenshot of XCode navigation bar to find option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6e3E.png)

I hope it can help!

Comment: Is there a solution to use this feature in iOS < 13 too? I have to support legacy iOS versions